# What is this SQL injection doing?

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

Long story short, through an old asp site I run someone found an unfiltered URL parameter and was able to run this query.  I'm trying to figure out what it DOES though...

The query should read:

```
select * from reserve where id = 345
```

the one that was ran was:

```
select * from reserve where id = 345 and ascii(substring((select concat(user,0x3a,password,0x3a,host) from mysql.user limit 0,1),17,1))=53
```

I'm really not sure what this obtains.  Any Input?

Comment: Looks like they're trying to narrow down the charset your db is using.

Comment: Weird, this query turns up all over the Internet - though not on any English sites heh..  The query looks useless to me though!  They're obviously looking for something..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be probing whether or not the web application is accessing the database as `root`.  Removing the `ascii(substring())` portions returns the following when run as root:

```
mysql> select concat(user,0x3a,password,0x3a,host) from mysql.user limit 0,1;
+--------------------------------------+
| concat(user,0x3a,password,0x3a,host) |
+--------------------------------------+
| root:<rootpw-hash>:localhost         |
+--------------------------------------+
```

Following a successful probe, they may then attempt to retrieve the contents of `mysql.user`  from which they can start cracking passwords against rainbow tables.

Comment: Interesting guess.  It looks like the query wants to know if the 17th character of that concatenation is ASCII char 53, which is the number 5.

Comment: @MikeChristensen I'm just investigating that.  In my case, it returned ascii 52 (numeral 4) so it may be looking for blank passwords or some well-known default password.

Comment: Yea, though you'd think they'd just query for `user='root'` and `password=<some known hash>` and be done with it..

Answer (score 2):

The SQL is trying to read user data from the My-Sql user table which typically contains a list of users and hosts that are allowed to access a given my-sql server.

It looks to me like the perp is trying to trick mysql into dumping the contents of the user table so they can then record the password hashes offline and dcrypt them to find valid logins.

If your web application is using a login that will allow access to the mysql users table, then this is a serious security flaw, if it's using a login that is only granted permission to the tables required for the app then no information will be obtainable.

**Security tip:** When setting up ANY kind of database it's vitally important that the application using does so with a login/access role that grants it ONLY what it needs.

If your application only ever needs to read data and never modify it, then it should never have any permissions other than to read.  You always need to double check this, because most database systems will by default create user roles for a given database with full read, create, modify privileges.

Always create a specific user, just for that db and or collection of tables, and always give that user the absolute minimum that's required, if your app does then get hacked with a cross site scripting attack, the most their going to get access too is that one specific database.

Answer (score 2):

The second part of where condition is really strange: it looks for a mysql credentials and process them as follows:

- concat(user,0x3a,password,0x3a,host) will be something like 'someUser:hisPass:localhost'
- the above string will be splitted in a smaller one
- the above string is converted to ascii code (you might know it from legacy languages as ord())
- the result of the conversion is compared to 53 integer

I suppose that the first part of WHERE statement (`id = 345`) will always return `true` while the second one is too specific, so the entire query will probably return an empty result all the time.

Answer (score 2):

the query is seemingly one from the a set of them:

- by changing the charcode and substring start position and you can find out all usernames and the corresponding password hashes (when the page renders as expected you have a char match)
- it allows to find out that the current user has access to the mysql schema.

Comment: What info do you have on the "set of them"?  Any links or anything?

Comment: @neil-m, I don't have any specific info. The query checks if the charcode of the 17th element of the concatenation of the username + passhash is 53. The attacker already knows that the current user has access to system tables, and has already read 16 characters from the resulted row.

Comment: @nail-m, and knowing the hashcode of your passwo rd, the attacker can search it in a rainbow table and find your password or another string that would would have the same hashvalue

Answer (score 2):

An sql injection exploit does not necessarily immediately output the query result to the attackers screen, often the result is only either an error, or no error, or maybe the injection causes a measurable (to the attacker) delay. in that way the attacker can obtain 1 bit of information per request.

By sending lots of requests, iterating over string positions, doing a binary search on the characters - or as in this case a linear search ( which may indicate that the attacker does not really understand what he is doing, but he will get there eventually ), he will be able to find all the characters in the mysql root user passwordhash. ( Which can possibly be bruteforced offline ).